# How to become pilot in India with lack of money

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots, airbus, boeing

Hello I am from India currently I am in class 12 pursuing PCM and want to become a commercial pilot but belong to a middle class family how can I pursue my dream. I can't afford course of 60 - 80lacs.

Comment: In my country our flag carrier (Turkish Airlines) has a program, they teach you how to fly in exchange for a contract with them for ten years. After ten years you're free to work wherever you want. Maybe there is a smiliar program in your country, you might want to look that up

Comment: Some airlines worldwide offer sponsored training. Try an internet search for "pilot cadetship" or try to search for "cadet" on [allflyingjobs.com](https://www.allflyingjobs.com/pilot-job-search?field_licence_authority=All&field_employment_type=All&field_licence_type=All&field_duration2=All&field_type_rating_required=All&field_currency=&field_time_on_type=&field_base=&field_commuting_available=All&field_req_total_time=&field_command_time=&field_comman_time_on_type2=&field_command_time_on_similar_ty=&field_english_proficiency_level_=&search_api_views_fulltext=cadet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airlines in most countries (outside of US and Canada) usually offer *ab initio* pilot programs, meaning they will train a pilot with no experience. Training will be paid for in the form of a loan which will be deducted from your future salary.

However there are some caveats. First, if you fail, you will be responsible for paying off the loan. There is no guarantee you will pass or be offered a job.

Second, these programs are highly competitive. Most programs require a college degree simply due to the number of applicants. Even then, you will have to be high in your class and be the best in all of their tests. I understand typical numbers at European airlines are 1 accepted out of 1,000 applicants.

Some people will suggest the military. Keep in mind that military pilot positions are often equally competitive. In the US, you must have a four year college degree to become a military pilot as well. I believe India is similar to the US as somebody after secondary education may apply to obtain a degree in a military academy, though that is highly competitive in itself.

Therefore, the best way may be to save money and/or get loans and gain your licenses yourself.

Answer (score 1):

China has a huge shortage of pilots. You could always apply to one of their training programs. You will have to commit to work for them for a number of years, and you will have to adapt to the culture, but if you don't have the money, you will have to compromise. Or you could do what I did, find a job at a flight school and trade work for training.